# How to create AsymmetricKeyParameter from the java.security.PublicKey

Tags: java, android, cryptography, rsa, spongycastle

I am trying to remove the spongy castle provider from my cryptography class and to use the Spongy castle light library directly (maven:com.madgag:sc-light-jdk15on:1.47.0.3)
I have a problem during changing a RSA encrypt logic, below is the code :

Original Code:

```
final PublicKey pKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "SC").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey));
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

Modified Code:

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter asypublicKey = PublicKeyFactory.createKey(publicKey);
org.spongycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding e = new org.spongycastle.crypto.encodings.PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());
e.init(true, asypublicKey);
```

the above code seems to be not equal as before. Can anyone tell me the equivalent of the orginal code I can rewrite with spongycastle library without using Javax.Crypto library?

Thx

Comment: I see few reasons to use Spongy for normal cryptographic operations. If the device contains a provider that performs fast, secure native cryptography then the benefits are lost. Just for my curiosity / knowledge: why are you switching to the lightweight API of Spongy?

Answer (score 1):

RSA PKCS#1 encryption is indeterministic. That's another way of saying that the PKCS#1 pads the plaintext message with random values before it performs modular exponentiation with the public exponent. If you're getting identical values then you know something is *wrong*, not right.

To test your code you need to simply decrypt the message. If it succeeds, then you know the ciphertext was generated the way it should be.